# Blocked UI state / Showing a loading animation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to show a loading animation while I do some processing on the data that is stored in the components state.
The boolean loading variable controls whether the loading animation is showing or not. This works when I do an asynchronous ajax request.
However, when I try to change the state of the loader in a component method, it does not work.
I tried to avoid the blocking of the UI with a small timeout (see comment in the code), but to no avail.

How do I show the loading animation when starting the calculations and hide it again afterwards?

```
calculateMovements() {

    // show the loading animation
    this.setState({
        loading: true
    });

    let data = this.state.data;

    // ...do expensive calculations on data here...

    // avoid blocking UI
    setTimeout(function() {
        // redraw with updated data
        this.setState({
            data,
            loading: false
        });
    }.bind(this), 10);

},

render() {
    return (
         <MuiThemeProvider>
            <div id="wrap">
                <Loader
                    visible={this.state.loading}
                />
                // etc. ...
```

Answer (score 1):

For heavy calculation in browsers, you really need to consider using workers. Workers are working in the background, and they designed to not block the UI,

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 0):

While calling setTimeOut you are actually passing the result of `setState` to `setTimeOut`. Do the `setTimeOut` like this...

```
calculateMovements() {
    this.setState({ loading: true});
    setTimeout(function() {
        // ...do expensive calculations on data here...
        this.setState({
            data: data,
            loading: false
        });
    }.bind(this), 10);
}
```

Then It will work fine.

Comment: You are right, I called the settimeout incorrectly. However, after implementing your change, the loading animation is still not showing. The whole page freezes for a few seconds before the final state (now wrapped in the setTimeout) is rendered.